# Spring boot 2.0.5.RELEASE with Jersey client 2.27 expects java.naming.factory.initial

Tags: java, spring-boot, jndi, jersey-2.0

I want to write a small command line tool using Spring Boot, that is using Jersey only for REST **client** calls. This tool should not have any JNDI or LDAP server etc. I think that Jersey expects to be in an application where JNDI is acctivated (Jave EE web container).

How can I switch off that for client app?

The exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientExecutorProvidersConfigurator.lookupManagedScheduledExecutorService(ClientExecutorProvidersConfigurator.java:198)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientExecutorProvidersConfigurator.init(ClientExecutorProvidersConfigurator.java:148)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:466)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:341)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:826)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getConfiguration(ClientRequest.java:285)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.validateHttpMethodAndEntity(JerseyInvocation.java:143)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:108)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:99)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:419)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:319)
        ...my code ...
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Also adding  -Djava.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory starts to connect localhost:389

Comment: The Jersey code looks like it should catch any `Exception` or `LinkageError` that's thrown when performing the JNDI lookup, log it, and continue. Is the exception above being thrown to your application code or are just seeing it in the logs?

Comment: I just see the exception in calling jersey related methods.. For me it looks some kind of internal work... possibly related with hk2 cache (that is aslo added as dependency, to solve another exception). Currently I'm playing with that and maybe later I can be sure what can be the root problem.

Comment: Failin row:
builder.get();// Exception row
2.25.1 - works, but there is no jersey-hk2 library for that version.
2.27 - have exception, but with that I need to add jersey-hk2. Without that Im getting: InjectionManagerFactory not found.

Comment: Also I extracted current problem code into small spring boot app for demonstration:  https://bitbucket.org/imreit/jersey-client

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is just in DEBUG mode logging more exceptions and thats it. Case closed.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and the solution is hidden in @Krabi latest comment, this is just **DEBUG** method and should be simply ignored.

```
2019-02-08 19:19:07.058 DEBUG 28437 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .j.c.ClientExecutorProvidersConfigurator : null

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
```